# Validating checkboxes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Let's assume i have a checkbox on a form. It's probably something like 'Agree to Terms and conditions' that has to be checked but can't be defaulted to checked when the form is loaded because the user has to 'read' the terms and conditions and agree.

[Angular documentation for checkbox](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) shows that there is no required attribute so is there an Angular way to make sure that the checkbox value is true/checked or do I have to do it manually in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

The `required` and `ngRequired` attributes are defined in the **[input](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)** directive, since a checkbox is also an input element, then the `required` and `ngRequired` attributes still apply.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XOed26DMxsDChtCeqsoQ?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" novalidate>
  <input type="checkbox" required="true" ng-model="termsAndConditions" name="termsAndConditions">
  {{form.termsAndConditions.$error | json}}
</form>
```